# ServiceStack on .NET Core using Authorization Policies

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, servicestack

Is there an example of using .NET Core authorization policies with ServiceStack based apis?

I have setup a .net core based ServiceStack site, I also have created an authorization policy. The next step, which I am having trouble with is injecting the authorization service into the ServiceStack implementation and passing in the user principal to the authorization service.

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._ Please have a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) article and find out which type of questions are on-topic. Asking for example is off-topic as quoted from that link

Comment: I clarified my question a bit more.  Sorry if I have offended you in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst ServiceStack doesn't know anything about .NET Core's Authentication, you can access the User assigned to the underlying .NET Core Request in your [filters](http://docs.servicestack.net/request-and-response-filters) with:

```
GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, requestDto) => {
    if (req.OriginalRequest is HttpRequest netcoreReq)
    {
        var user = netcoreReq.HttpContext.user;
    }
});
```